# Larevel выполнить запрос (функцию) через некоторое время

Tags: laravel

У меня есть запрос к БД:

```js
$having = new Having();
$having->part_shop_id = $shop->pivot->id;
$having->user_id = $user->id;
$user->havings()->save($having);
```

Этот запрос должен выполнится через n часов, которые указаны в `$shop-delivery_time`. Как это сделать?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues
Рассмотрите это

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно Вас понял, то вы хотите отложенную задачу. Для этого Вам подойдёт связка Job + taskShedule. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling

Вам нужно создать job`у и в метод handle() поместить исполняемый код. После этого поместить её в Kernel на отложенный запуск https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#scheduling-queued-jobs.

Если же вам просто нужно отложить выполнение задачи на n времени от запроса пользователя, то для этого можно использовать delay() метод при запуске задачи https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#delayed-dispatching